# How to resize a chart and paste chart in specific cell - excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to paste a chart in a specific location and to resize it all in the same sub. So far this is the code I have:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:E12").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

With Sheet2
intCount = .Shapes.Count
   For i = intCount To 1 Step -1 
      With .Shapes.Item(i)
         If .Name <> "Picture" Then 
             .Delete
         End If
      End With
   Next i

  .Paste
  Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
  Set shp.Name = "Picture"
  
  shp.Left = .range("P14").Left
  shp.Top = .range("P14").Top
  
  destination.Shapes.Item(1).Height = range("A1:E12").Height
End With
```

Also, when it pastes, it sometimes picks up data from elsewhere in the sheet, that is outside of the range. Not sure how to fix that either.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code copies `A1:E12` into your chart as a picture.  Is this your true intention, or do you simply want to create a chart from the data in `A1:E12`?

Comment: When deleting objects, such as shapes, you'll need to delete them in reverse order.

Comment: With regards to your line deleting the shapes, you'll need to replace the comma ( , ) with a dot ( . ).

Comment: @Domenic when you say delete in reverse order, do you mean something like: For i=intCount to 1? And yes, I need to turn it into a picture so I can put it over hidden rows. Do you have any idea how to paste the picture in a particular location? Thanks!

Comment: To delete in reverse order, you'll need to provide the step value as well.  So it should be `For i = intCount  To 1 Step -1`.

Comment: So you don't actually need to create a chart, right?  You simply want to copy your range as a picture to a specific location and resize, right?

Comment: @Domenic, Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do, but it is not exactly doing what I would like it do. And thank you, I will try the reverse order

Comment: @domenic Hi! I noticed the second part of your answer has disappeared, was this intentional?

Comment: Yes. I understand that you want to copy A1:E12 as a picture, paste it in your other worksheet, position the picture at the desired location, and adjust its height.  Prior to that, though, it's unclear to me what it is you want to do.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: As of now, the issue is that the code above is interfering with some of the other elements in the sheet, and it will behave randomly. For instance, sometimes it will enlarge a different image or elongate a button.  what could cause this?

Comment: Previously you said that it did not delete the copied pasted picture.  Now you're saying that you have another issue.  Very confusing.  The only line on your latest code that changes the size of a shape is `Destination.Shapes . . .`

Comment: @Domenic Yes thats the problem, the code is behaving very randomly and will have different problems each time.  Should we continue in the chat?

Comment: I don't know which sheet `Destination` refers to, but I'm assuming that you want to resize the pasted picture to the same size as `A1:E12`.  If so, try `shp.Height = Sheet1.Range("A1:E12").Height`.